# User login in codeigniter with out database and use json format instead of

Tags: json, codeigniter

I am trying to login and register users in codeigniter but with out using database and I would like to use `json` instead of database.

Can anyone give me small example that how can we do this in codeigniter.

I have worked login and registration with using database and I don't have idea of how we can do by using json.

Can any one explain me and give me small example of how to do that.

Comment: Json isn't a database it's just a means of presenting data.

Comment: okay can you please give me one example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes you can use helper `FILE` and save data in in that file.

To write / Access data, you need to do few steps:

- Load File Helper
- Check if File exists
- Get all text and decode in array (I assume you will store in JSON format)
- Fetch username/password and verify
- Add new username/password in that array
- Convert into JSON and save in file

Comment: if it is possible can you please give me example

Comment: Well, Right now I haven't but if you are interested I can make for you. 
Or you may share your tries with me at ping@naveedramzan.com